# Increase Value of Dictionary at a specified Key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a bool variable and a Dictionary.
if it is true I have to increase value of my dictionary by 1 at a specified Key.

My Code :

```
 private void Process(Person person)
 {
     isSendMailSuccessful = true;

     if (isSendMailSuccessful)
     {
         MyDictionary.Where(i => i.Key == person.personID);
         // I need to increase Value of that ID by 1
     }
 }
```

Comment: I know this is probably only demo code but isSendMailSuccessful will always be true so the assignment of the value true to it and the subsequent if statement are redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why are you using LINQ fot this, and not just the Indexer of the Dictionary?

Something like

```
MyDictionary[person.personID] += 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

No reason to use LINQ here.

Assuming your dictionary is `Dictionary<int,int>`, you can simply do `myDictionary[person.PersonID]++;`.

You should use `ContainsKey` first so verify that the key exist in the dictionary, else it will throw an exception if you try to change a dictionary entry that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyDictionary[person.personID] += 1;
```

Or use ContainsKey first if you aren't sure the key exists.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something obvious:

```
MyDictionary[person.personID] += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Process(Person person)
 {
     isSendMailSuccessful = true;

     if (isSendMailSuccessful)
     {
         MyDictionary[person.personID] += 1;
     }
 }
```

Having written that I'm now no longer sure as to why I didn't use `++`, and whether `+= 1` will work or whether you'd have to use: `MyDictionary[person.personID] = MyDictionary[person.personID] + 1`;